# How do I allow (remote) IISReset through the firewall on Win Server 2008

Tags: iis, firewall, iisreset

I'm trying to run the following, to reset IIS on a remote machine.

`IISReset <remoteMachine>`

If I disable the domain firewall, everything works fine. With the firewall enabled, I get

`The RPC server is unavailable.`

Initially I tried enabling `Remote Administration (RPC-EPMAP)` and any other rules that looked even tenuously related. Then I tried enabling all the predefined rules, but with no success.